Airflow DAG throws GlueJobOperator is not JSON serializable
Below Airflow task throws an error:
[2024-08-07T09:05:00.142+0000] {{xcom.py:664}} ERROR - Object of type GlueJobOperator is not JSON serializable. If you are using pickle instead of JSON for XCom, then you need to enable pickle support for XCom in your airflow config or make sure to decorate your object with attr.

Code:
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.glue import GlueJobOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from airflow.decorators import task_group, task, dag
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

from utils.environment_config import EnvironmentConfig  # noqa: E402

config = EnvironmentConfig(__file__)

import json


params_one = ["value"]
params_two = ["1","2"]

params_three = [4, 12, 52]
params_four = [3]
param_five = ["col"]

playground_bucket = config.get_environment_variable("playground_bucket_name", default_var="undefined")
intermittent_data_location = config.get_environment_variable("stage3_output_intermittent_location", default_var="undefined")
stage3_task_role = config.get_environment_variable("stage3_task_role", default_var="undefined")
join_bridge_script = config.get_bridge_script("join_bridge_script.py")


#default_args={ "donot_pickle": "True" }
@dag(dag_id='chore_task_group_stage3', schedule=None, catchup=False)
def pipeline():

    @task
    def lag_tasks_with_filter(
        param_one,
        demo,
        param_three,
        param_four,
        ,
        lag_task_role,
        intermittent_data_location,
        playground_bucket
    ):

        return GlueJobOperator(
            task_id=f"create_task_{param_one}_{param_two}_w{param_three}param_four{param_four}param_five{param_five}",
            job_name=config.generate_job_name(f"param_four{param_four}-weeks{param_three}-" + f"filter{param_five}-job-{param_one}-{param_two}"),
            script_location=config.get_bridge_script("lags_bridge_script.py"),
            iam_role_name=lag_task_role,
            script_args={
                    "--lagWithCatPath": f"s3://{intermittent_data_location}/output/with_cat" + f"/param_one={param_one}/param_two={param_two}",
                    "--rawDataInputPath": f"s3://{playground_bucket}/output/oneyear" + f"/param_one={param_one}/param_two={param_two}/",
                    "--numberOfLagWeeks": str(param_four),
                    "--windowSizeWeeks": str(param_three),
                    "--filterCol": param_five,
                    "--taskId": f"create_task_{param_one}_{param_two}_w{param_three}param_four{param_four}param_five{param_five}",    
            },
            create_job_kwargs={
                    "WorkerType": "G.2X",
                    "NumberOfWorkers": 5,
                    "GlueVersion": "4.0",
                    "DefaultArguments": {
                                        "--job-language": "python",
                                        "--enable-job-insights": "true",
                                        "--enable-metrics": "true",
                                        "--enable-auto-scaling": "true",
                                        "--enable-observability-metrics": "true",
                                        "--TempDir": f"s3://{config.get_environment_variable('glue_tmp_dir_location', default_var='undefined')}",
                                        "--extra-py-files": config.get_asset_file_location(
                                            "ctc_telligence_forecasting_data_product-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl"
                                        ),
                                        "--enable-spark-ui": "true",
                                        "--spark-event-logs-path": f"s3://{config.get_environment_variable('glue_spark_ui_logs_location', default_var='undefined')}",
                                    },
            },
            update_config=True,
        )


    ts = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
    te = DummyOperator(task_id='end')
    t1 = lag_tasks_with_filter.partial(lag_task_role=stage3_task_role, intermittent_data_location=intermittent_data_location, playground_bucket=playground_bucket).expand(param_one=params_one, param_two=params_two, param_three=params_three, param_four=params_four, param_five=param_five)

    # setting dependencies
    ts >> t1 >> te

pipeline()

When removing return, DAG passes but Glue jobs don't get created and triggered.
I want to keep @task decorator syntax since it allows for creating mapped instances with expand().

I believe traditional operators also support the "expand" method and there is no need for a @task wrapper here. See - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html#mapping-with-non-taskflow-operators
upd#1
Summary of changes, The code is based on the provided example:

Added helper task to prepare the cartesian product of configs based on combinations from param_two and param_three
Replaced Dummy to EmptyOperator (Dummy was deprecated some time ago, it's preferable to use Empty instead)
Removed task flow wrapper from TraditionalOperator; utilized expand_kwargs to pass mapping for iteration

from typing import Any
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.glue import GlueJobOperator
from airflow.decorators import task, dag

# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

# from utils.environment_config import EnvironmentConfig  # noqa: E402

# config = EnvironmentConfig(__file__)

import json


playground_bucket = (
    "s3://mydummys3bucket"  # config.get_environment_variable("playground_bucket_name", default_var="undefined")
)
intermittent_data_location = "myintermittent_data_location"  # config.get_environment_variable("stage3_output_intermittent_location", default_var="undefined")
lag_task_role = "mystage3_task_role"  # config.get_environment_variable("stage3_task_role", default_var="undefined")
join_bridge_script = "myjoin_bridge_script"  # config.get_bridge_script("join_bridge_script.py")

param_one = ["value"]
param_two = ["1", "2"]
param_three = [4, 12, 52]
param_four = [3]
param_five = ["col"]


@dag(dag_id="chore_task_group_stage3", schedule=None, catchup=False)
def pipeline():

    ts = EmptyOperator(task_id="start")

    @task
    def create_task_mappings(
        param_one, param_two, param_three, param_four, param_five, intermittent_data_location, playground_bucket
    ) -> dict[str, Any]:
        job_name = f"param_four{param_four}-weeks{param_three}-" + f"filter{param_five}-job-{param_one}-{param_two}"
        script_args = {
            "--lagWithCatPath": f"s3://{intermittent_data_location}/output/with_cat"
            + f"/param_one={param_one}/param_two={param_two}",
            "--rawDataInputPath": f"s3://{playground_bucket}/output/oneyear"
            + f"/param_one={param_one}/param_two={param_two}/",
            "--numberOfLagWeeks": str(param_four),
            "--windowSizeWeeks": str(param_three),
            "--filterCol": param_five,
            "--taskId": f"create_task_{param_one}_{param_two}_w{param_three}param_four{param_four}param_five{param_five}",
        }

        return {"job_name": job_name, "script_args": script_args}

    created_mappings = create_task_mappings.partial(
        param_one=param_one,
        param_four=param_four,
        param_five=param_five,
        intermittent_data_location=intermittent_data_location,
        playground_bucket=playground_bucket,
    ).expand(param_three=param_three, param_two=param_two)

    t1 = GlueJobOperator.partial(
        task_id="lag_tasks_with_filter",
        create_job_kwargs={
            "WorkerType": "G.2X",
            "NumberOfWorkers": 5,
            "GlueVersion": "4.0",
            "DefaultArguments": {
                "--job-language": "python",
                "--enable-job-insights": "true",
                "--enable-metrics": "true",
                "--enable-auto-scaling": "true",
                "--enable-observability-metrics": "true",
                "--TempDir": f"s3://{playground_bucket}/temp",
                "--extra-py-files": "ctc_telligence_forecasting_data_product-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl",
                "--enable-spark-ui": "true",
                "--spark-event-logs-path": f"s3://{playground_bucket}/logs",
            },
        },
        iam_role_name=lag_task_role,
        script_location=join_bridge_script,
        update_config=True,
    ).expand_kwargs(created_mappings)

    te = EmptyOperator(task_id="end")

    ts >> created_mappings >> t1 >> te


pipeline()

References:
Cross-product - https://www.astronomer.io/docs/learn/dynamic-tasks#cross-product
Multiple params to Traditional Operator - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html#assigning-multiple-parameters-to-a-non-taskflow-operator

I tried but expand didn't work with traditional one.

Could you provide a reproducible example to test it out? I assume something might be defined wrong

Updated the code.

@marcin2x4 Could you try the example above and check whether it satisfies your needs?

I'll let you know tomorrow. Great thanks!

Getting close but got an error GlueArgumentError: the following arguments are required: --dagId

Overall, your solution works! Great thanks! I wasn't aware that partial can be used directly on a operator too. What i did was getting wrong combination o classic/decorator to work together,
